# SQL Server issue with select and group by with calculated columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL I am trying to build:

```
select 
    a.Name,
    (SELECT COUNT(b.PlannedCollectionDate) WHERE b.PlannedCollectionDate < GETDATE()) AS Due,
    (SELECT COUNT(b.PlannedCollectionDate) WHERE b.PlannedCollectionDate = GETDATE()) AS Today,
    (SELECT COUNT(b.PlannedCollectionDate) WHERE b.PlannedCollectionDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())) AS Expected,
    (SELECT COUNT(b.PlannedCollectionDate) WHERE b.PlannedCollectionDate > DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())) AS Planned
from Centers AS a
INNER JOIN Collections AS b
ON a.Id = b.CenterId
GROUP BY a.Name
```

But I get an error:

> Column 'Collections.PlannedCollectionDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I know I could do something like this:

```
select 
    a.Name,
    (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Collections WHERE CenterId = a.Id AND PlannedCollectionDate < GETDATE()) AS Due,
    (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Collections WHERE CenterId = a.Id AND PlannedCollectionDate = GETDATE()) AS Today,
    (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Collections WHERE CenterId = a.Id AND PlannedCollectionDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())) AS Expected,
    (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Collections WHERE CenterId = a.Id AND PlannedCollectionDate > DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())) AS Planned
from Centers AS a
```

But I assume that is slower because I have to do multiple selects from the same table (Collections).

So, my question is, what can I do to make my first query work? I don't think grouping by PlannedCollectionDate is right, because it will mess up my **count**

Comment: Either GROUP BY **OR** correlated sub-queries!

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: Just do something like this for each condition this is just an example of the first column: `COUNT(CASE WHEN b.PlannedCollectionDate < GETDATE() THEN 1 END)`

Comment: Do a sub-query that aggregates. Then JOIN.

Comment: @r3plica the query doesn't make much sense right now. You ask for *unique* `Name` values with that `GROUP BY` but the subqueries ask for *totals*. `GROUP BY` is used when you want to use aggregations in `SELECT`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select ce.Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN co.PlannedCollectionDate < GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Due,
       SUM(CASE WHEN co.PlannedCollectionDate = GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Today,
       SUM(CASE WHEN co.PlannedCollectionDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Expected,
       SUM(CASE WHEN co.PlannedCollectionDate > DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Planned
from Centers ce join
     Collections co
     on ce.Id = co.CenterId
group by ce.Name;
```

This implements what you have written.  Do note the use of *meaningful* table aliases.

However, it will not do what you want, because `GETDATE()` has a time component.  To fix that, convert it to a date:

```
select ce.Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN co.PlannedCollectionDate < CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Due,
       SUM(CASE WHEN co.PlannedCollectionDate = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Today,
       SUM(CASE WHEN co.PlannedCollectionDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Expected,
       SUM(CASE WHEN co.PlannedCollectionDate > DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Planned
from Centers ce join
     Collections co
     on ce.Id = co.CenterId
group by ce.Name;
```

Note that this assumes that `PlannedCollectionDate` does not have a time component.